# Converting grid corners from UTM to degrees, minutes, and second in QGIS

Tags: qgis, convert, vector-grid, c, degrees-minutes-seconds

I have a shapefile of a 10km grid that is in UTM projection but I would like to convert all coordinates to Degrees, Minutes, and Seconds. The attribute table has corners (Top, Bottom, left, and right). These are the ones I would like to convert to DMS. How can I do that in QGIS?

I tried to save as CSV but I did not get the coordinates of all corners. I have also used 'add geometry attribute' but it also did not give the DMS coordinates.

Here is how the grid looks like:
[image: Attribute table of the grids]

Comment: Please decide which software you want to use. Please add what you researched, as well was what you tried so far and where you're stuck.

Comment: Thank you for adding the details. Are you aware that `add geometry attributes` uses the current CRS of the layer? So you either need to reproject your data to EPSG:4326, or use the field calculator expression `transform()` in order to add the coordinates as decimal degrees.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use these expressions:

left:

```
to_dms(x_min(transform($geometry,layer_property(@layer,'crs'),'EPSG:4326')),'x',3)
```

top:

```
to_dms(y_max(transform($geometry,layer_property(@layer,'crs'),'EPSG:4326')),'y',3)
```

right:

```
to_dms(x_max(transform($geometry,layer_property(@layer,'crs'),'EPSG:4326')),'x',3)
```

bottom:

```
to_dms(y_min(transform($geometry,layer_property(@layer,'crs'),'EPSG:4326')),'y',3)
```

- The last number (3 in my example) specifies the coordinate precision. Change that if you want to.
- You can also add `,'aligned'` or `,'suffix'` behind the coordinate precision to format your output. E.g. `to_dms(y_min(transform($geometry,layer_property(@layer,'crs'),'EPSG:4326')),'y',3,'suffix')`
- Note that your output field must be of type `string`

*Further explanation: First we get the geometry by using `$geometry` and `transform()` it from the layers source CRS (`layer_property(@layer,'crs')`) to WGS84 (`'EPSG:4326'`). Then we get the max or min coordinates by using `x_min()`, `y_max()` and so on, which are equal to `left`, `top`, etc.. Finally we convert the transformed coordinate to degree, minute and second by using `to_dms()`.
See QGIS docs for information about this expression: https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#to-dms*

Comment: Works Completely well. Thank you.